# After updating Nuget Packages Jquery and its dependencies are "undefined"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget

I just bulk updated all the Nuget packages in my MVC-4 project and now the IE (version 10) debugger basically can't find Jquery. The first error is the following:

```
> "Unhandled exception at line 349, column 1 in
> http://localhost:49808/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.js
> 
> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'JSON' is undefined  "
```

Line 349 is the start of jQuery.extend

The debugger runs just fine in all other browsers, but I'd prefer to use IE.

Thanks in advance for advice on how to fix this.

Comment: Ensure you are not in compatability mode with IE...jquery 2.x will not work with IE 6/7/8: http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/

Comment: @Tommy, thank you very much. This was indeed the problem. (I don't use IE for anything but development so had no idea that the little broken icon needed to be gray, not blue. I wouldn't put it so near the reload icon... ) I don't use Stackoverflow very often either, so may be missing a  checkmark to check, but would like to check this as an answer.

Comment: awesome, glad it worked!  Since I was not 100% that this was your issue, I only posted it as a comment initially.  I have moved the comment as an answer, you should now be able to accept by clicking the checkmark beside the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new release of jQuery (version 2.0), it is not compatible with IE 6/7/8, you would need to stick with the jQuery version 1.9.x branch if you need to support those versions of IE.  Also, IE compatibility mode will cause IE 9/10 to act as 6/7/8 and would also cause a jQuery failure of the new 2.x versions.

Check to ensure that you are not in IE compatibility mode in your test environment IE, that would cause the new jQuery to fail.

http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/